# How to use drift correction

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm wondering how exactly one use drift correction? It seem to refuse to work with area learning (error message: "Drift-correction mode is incompatible with learning mode or ADF loading."), something the documents lead me to believe that it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drift correction is only used for single session AR experiences. It handles the case when device lost tracking in AR and relocalize the device back to previously visited area. Currently, drift correction cannot be used for saving ADF (a.k.a Area Learning).

You can basically think it as a smaller but much denser ADF that can be used in realtime without saving/loading.

Comment: Since it does not work at all with area learning, I guess the guide doc needs an update. The doc indicates that drift correction is a feature of Area Learning.

Comment: For instance:
"You will also need to correct the "drift" problem. Both of these issues are addressed by the next core technology, Area Learning.";
"When a Tango device has learned an area, there are two key things it can do ... 1. Improve the accuracy of the trajectory by performing "drift corrections."";
"With Area Learning turned on, the Tango device remembers ... This memory allows the system to perform drift corrections";
And so on.

Comment: I think that's true. There's a mis-match of what drift-correction means in those two contexts. Comment noted.